# Magento 1.9: is there a way to rename a route without renaming the entire module?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9

I am working on a project where a module named Namespace_Ticket was adapted to work as an invoices list.

However, the URL to access this module is like this:

```
http://dev.local/index.php/tickets/index/index/ticket_id/9568/
```

I would like to be able to remove the word "tickets" from the URL and replace it with "invoice". I want my URL to look like this:

```
http://dev.local/index.php/invoices/index/index/invoice_id/9568/
```

Is there a way I can do it without having to rename the entire module?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Router name is defined in module's `etc/config.xml` file, you will find a code similar to below

```
<routers>
    <modulename> <!--or this may be ticket -->
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
           <module>Namespace_Ticket</module>
           <frontName>tickets</frontName> <!-- You have to change this value to change the router -->
        </args>
    </modulename>
</routers>
```

Router need to be defined separately for both admin and frontend, you can found both under `<frontend>` and `<admin>` nodes.

**After changing router frontname, make sure that you have to change router wherever the url is used throughout the site.**

Comment: Thank you. I tried to change the **frontName** but for some reason it was not working. I figured I had 2 modules with the same name but within different code pools and I was changing the wrong module. Thank you again.

Comment: @AndresaKrul it may not work if there is already a module with same router